# How to flush text to the right in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have this

```
.--------------------------------------.
| Left                           Right |
'--------------------------------------'
```

One solution (with Bootstrap) is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col ">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a simpler way such as this?

```
<div>
Left <span class="hfill">Right</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `float:right` ?

Comment: What version of bootstrap? Are you wanting to omit any bootstrap utility classes?

Comment: `<div style="display: flex">
Left <span style="margin-left: auto">Right</span>
</div>` ... it takes only 2 properties, though don't use inline styles

Comment: As suggested, float might be the simplest, but more importantly, how do you want those 2 to render when it comes to same height, wrapping etc. When we know that we know what to suggest, making it more about _what needed_ than _simpler_.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4

Comment: `<div>Left<span class="float-right">Right</span></div>`

Comment: @LGSon, thanks, but the other question you are referring to  is not the same. I am asking if there is a simpler way to achieve it with less HTML tags.

Comment: @nowox Questions asking about _"simpler ways"_ are too broad, hence being off topic. The dupe link + comments + answers here would be a good start for you. I also think it is better, from a _"future users"_ perspective, to close as a dupe than as off topic.

Comment: I added one more link to the dupe list, which shows some more built-in classes how to align horizontal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using bootstrap 4

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div>Left</div>
    <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

without bootstrap

```css
.someClass {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass">
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```